# Add a UIView using Interface Builder, remove, then add to another view

Tags: ios, uiview, hide, addition

Due to problems having a split view within a tab view, I have created my application as a tab view and am trying to simulate split view functionality within one of my tabs.

I have created the left hand side panel of the split view in the Interface Builder in the landscape orientation. When the user changes to portrait, I want to programmatically remove the left hand side panel from the view and add it to a popover panel to be launched from a toolbar button. Then vice versa, of course.

I thought I knew how to do this, but it's not working. I've created a UIViewController which does this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [playMakerToolsView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:playMakerToolsView];
}
```

...where `playMakerToolsView` is the reference to the UIView added from the Interface Builder.

But I'm finding when I launch this popover, it doesn't seem to show correctly. The popover is blank.

I'm relatively new to iOS development so I'm probably missing something obvious. If you could point me in the right direction that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are removing left side view? you can just hide it and set frames for main view.

Comment: Sorry, n00b here, I have no idea what you mean! What does "set frames" mean? How does this add it to the popover view?

Comment: @user700774 you can just hide the view from left side and assign that to popoverViewController's view and unhide. Hope you understand.

Comment: Hmmm, kind of. So you're saying that the view would be added to two parents at the same time, and just hidden in one and showing in the other? That doesn't sound like it would work - how would you specify which you're showing and which you're not? Are there any examples of this that I could use?

Comment: How about creating two instances of the same view one for popover and one for left panel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you retaining playMakerToolsView anywhere? If not, when you remove it from the superview it is potentially up for dealloc'ing.